# Bounty chronology, possible or N/A?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I just started my first bounty on Ask Ubuntu! A very special one as I offered it on [another person's question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37972/diagnose-brightness-control). Btw, gaining the [Investor Badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/45/investor?userid=18140).

Actually I'm planning to keep track of them using [my profile space](https://askubuntu.com/users/18140/guandalino), but I'd really love to know if there is a better way to do this. I'd love to see something like *Bounties* after Info, Reputation, Activity, etc. links.

Does this make sense to anyone? Or is it just me?

Thanks

Comment: you can also go through the reputation page and spot your bounties by the "-100" entries, and get a quick overview on the reputation graph (red bars down the bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's now a Bounty tab in your user page:

Example:

- https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro?tab=bounties

Comment: Awesome, thanks.